# reflect.DeepEqual() is returning false but slices are same

Tags: go, slice, reflect

I am comparing two slices, both of type `[]int`. One is coming in to API in the form of json and parsed as go struct. In the struct, it is intialized as empty `[]int{}`.  Second is saved in the database (MongoDb) and is fetched and mapped to same struct type.

In some cases, the two slices are completely blank. But comparison is returning `false`.

`reflect.DeepEqual(oldSettings.S1, newSettings.S1)`

I have also checked both fields type using `reflect.TypeOf(newSettings.S1)`. It is retuning `[]int` for both.

Please consider this playground link for structure example.

https://play.golang.org/p/1JTUCPImxwq

```
type OldSettings struct {
    S1 []int
}

type NewSettings struct {
    S1 []int
}

func main() {
    oldSettings := OldSettings{}
    newSettings := NewSettings{}

    if reflect.DeepEqual(oldSettings.S1, newSettings.S1) == false {
        fmt.Println("not equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("equal")
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

[`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) returns `false` if one slice is `nil`, and the other is a non-`nil` slice with `0` length. Quoting from doc of `reflect.DeepEqual()`:

> Slice values are deeply equal when all of the following are true: they are both nil or both non-nil, they have the same length, and either they point to the same initial entry of the same underlying array (that is, &x[0] == &y[0]) or their corresponding elements (up to length) are deeply equal. Note that a non-nil empty slice and a nil slice (for example, []byte{} and []byte(nil)) are not deeply equal.

Example:

```
oldSettings := OldSettings{S1: []int{}}
newSettings := NewSettings{}

if reflect.DeepEqual(oldSettings.S1, newSettings.S1) == false {
    fmt.Println("not equal")
} else {
    fmt.Println("equal")
}
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FgUgAAgu-O0)):

```
not equal
```

If the `S1` field is not present in your JSON or MongoDB source, after unmarshaling it will be left `nil`. But if it exists as an empty array, an empty, non-`nil` slice will be created for it in Go.

Example proving it:

```
var s struct {
    S1 []int
}

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{}`), &s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(s, s.S1 == nil)

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"S1":[]}`), &s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(s, s.S1 == nil)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b59bSU1zL5h)):

```
{[]} true
{[]} false
```